# Facebook Login Integration in AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

I have come across an issue while integrating Facebook login with AEM.

I took reference from below link

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/social_communities/social_connect.html

Although everything is working fine but on welcome page it is not displaying the logged in user name the way it is working for Geometrixx Outdoors website.

Instead it is displaiying the ID only.

Any suggestions who have already worked on this integration? :)

Answer (score 5):

When your user logs in from facebook,it will exist as a user in /home/users/facebook under the group you have specified.If it is not there,you need to do it.Dont forget to check the about me part shown in figure ,so that user can save the info with the help of this.User in your aem will fetch only those info which you check here,

[image]

And in the welcome page,you need to fetch the user-info from that group and show it on your welcome page,it will not be on the fly.You need to do it like geomatrix.

I have done work on this integration,If you need further help,feel free to ask me.